# open source web interface to create svn projects?

Tags: svn, web-applications, hosting

Is there an open source web front for me to put on my server? I would like to give friends a url so we all can create our own svn projects without restrictions and great speed. optional SSL would be nice with it too.

Web interface like trac is a bonus

Answer (score 0):

There are several options available, the one i have seen in use is [WebSVN](http://websvn.tigris.org/). Have you tried googling for Web based SVN ?

Comment: WebSVN looks like it shows you what is in your SVN. It doesnt seem like it will allow you to create a project via the web interface and add/remove users.